# Google Places Autocomplete for French Cities

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm building a Cities autocomplete for a French web app. In France, each city has a postcode that is unique to it. For instance: Versailles has postcode: **78000**.

So in theory, you can get a postcode by typing a city, and get a city by typing its postcode.

According to Google Places documentation, you can get postcode by setting the types to `'(regions)'`: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3

I have tried both `'(regions)'` and `'(cities)'` but can't get it to return the postcode:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {
    types: '(regions)',
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'fr'
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sikko/mp4hLf7p/1/

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to use geocoder after the autocomplete return in order to get a detailed address as you want

Answer (score 1):

It returns postal code. 4-th element in address_components.

{
    "long_name": "75003",
    "short_name": "75003",
    "types": [
      "postal_code"
    ]
  }